# Automation testing in Java or Android possible

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, automation, wifi

I am working on writing automation to test hardware (Wi-fi, Ethernet, Bluetooth, GPS and keyboard). Nothing is automated its all manual testing at the moment. the product will load a live USB OS and from there it will run a application. I need to write Java code which will launch the application, selects the proper options and spits out the pass or fail results. This all things needs to be developed in Java if possible or Android, I am not sure if I am allowed to use any existing third party tool.

If this is possible to write on Java or Android are there any tutorials or if there any third party suggestions I appreciate information in general about this if this is at all possible and where to look for this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is Cucumber framework. It is a framework which automates the testing for you. You write some calabash/ruby scripts and open up a port on your network and Cucumber takes care from there on.

Check this link: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki
Also see: http://cukes.info/

Also search for the **cucumber_book** by Matt Wynee if you can get one. It is a real good reference.

Comment: Interesting thank you , are there examples of basic wifi,ethernet, bluetooth, gps, and keyboard testing included in the book ?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by wifi,keyboard testing. If you mean checking whether a keyboard has been displayed on tapping the screen, or you can see the gps icon and so on, then yes you can certainly do that. The book is for actually getting you started on cucumber..the setup, writing scripts and so on. You can probably see some example on the github link which i posted. And don't forget to accept and upvote if it helped you. Cheers!

Comment: well here is what i am looking for:
Test the onboard keyboard to see if it works.
Test the onboard Bluetooth if it can find or discover a specific device.
Test the ethernet if it can locate a file within the network (already have a file checker example that does that.) 
these types of tests. I will check out the book though it seems interesting enough